# Is there a clojure Ring adapter for Vertx?

Tags: clojure, ring

I am using clojure with Vertx and can see my request/response roundtrip. However I would like to leverage the Ring framework, which comes with only a Jetty adapter. Does anyone know of a ready made one for Vertx? I am interested in learning how to write my own, but am short of time to research it.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I should add that my specific need is to have an ultra scalable and secure HTTP REST service.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out.  https://github.com/RallySoftware/netty-ring-adapter It is a drop in replacement for Jetty using Netty.

Comment: Thanks! It looks good and I will probably end up using it. The only thing is, SSL is not supported yet. Also, it seems Vertx already offers a lot of higher-level primitives on top of Netty, including HTTP/SSL and parameter extraction. So it seems like it may be worth to write my own plumbing for now? However I recognize that using Ring and plugging in another adapter if needed is more efficient.

Comment: Parameter extraction is a middleware built into the ring library.  As far as https, I know the author and we will need soon on our project.  I will put in a good word for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about vertx myself, but you should be aware that Jetty is certainly not the only webserver that ring can interoperate with: it's the only one bundled into ring proper, but a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=clojure+ring+adapter+-jetty) reveals a handful of other adapters, eg for netty, simpleweb, mongrel2, and finagle. I did find a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vertx/WvMNPUgDF7A/q_kQM7f-ixEJ) about vertx/clojure interop on the google group, though. Looks half-baked and perhaps never finished, but worth looking into at least.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked-out Netty, Grizzly and Vertx so far, and it seems Vertx is the way to go, especially because it is so well documented compared to most others in Java land - indeed it seems to be the closest thing to 'just work out of the box' like Ruby/Rails and Node.js. I'll look at what you suggest here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so - although such adapter would be ultimately cool!

Have you checked [http-kit](http://http-kit.org/)? 
It seems to be fairly performance-effective (haven't checked it myself though) and is 99.9% Ring-compatible.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out and may end up using it. This is great info.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clojure module [here](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-clojure) thats being actively developed. There is a ring adapter [here](https://github.com/stream1984/ring-vertx-adapter) .